# Combine values of JSON array by matching ID -

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to combine the values of a JSON object to display full throughput for traffic destined for a specific target, instead of tiny values to the same address.

I have read through hundreds of threads and they all seem to revolve around adding values from different arrays into one using an individual key, or by combining the values into a single field.

The key here is the IP address, the values to add are RX and TX

The data I have looks like this:

```
[
  {"macProtocol": "ip", "ipProtocol": "tcp", "dstAddress": "X.60.219.13", "tx":50, "rx":100},
  {"macProtocol": "ip", "ipProtocol": "tcp", "dstAddress": "X.60.219.13", "tx":50, "rx":100},
  {"macProtocol": "ip", "ipProtocol": "tcp", "dstAddress": "X.60.219.13", "tx":50, "rx":100},
  {"macProtocol": "ip", "ipProtocol": "tcp", "dstAddress": "X.60.219.13", "tx":50, "rx":100},
  {"macProtocol": "ip", "ipProtocol": "udp", "dstAddress": "X.172.63.97", "tx":500, "rx":750},
  {"macProtocol": "ip", "ipProtocol": "udp", "dstAddress": "X.189.157.90", "tx":1000, "rx":2776},
  {"macProtocol": "ip", "ipProtocol": "udp", "dstAddress": "X.212.176.21", "tx":70, "rx":300},
]
```

What I would like to turn this into:

```
[
  {"macProtocol": "ip", "ipProtocol": "tcp", "dstAddress": "X.60.219.13", "tx": 200, "rx": 400},
  {"macProtocol": "ip", "ipProtocol": "udp", "dstAddress": "X.172.63.97", "tx": 500, "rx": 750},
  {"macProtocol": "ip", "ipProtocol": "udp", "dstAddress": "X.189.157.90", "tx": 1000, "rx": 2776},
  {"macProtocol": "ip", "ipProtocol": "udp", "dstAddress": "X.212.176.21", "tx": 70, "rx": 300},
]
```

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: Thanks. JSON array.

Comment: There's also no such thing as a "JSON array". What you have there is an _array of objects_

Comment: That said... What have you tried so far to solve the problem on your own?

Comment: I searched the internet for JSON Objects after you posted your initial comment and came across this:

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp

I have tried this piece of code found on this site with a few variations, however it just adds the values, and does not combine them. I will update with the code.

Comment: w3school got better but do yourself a favor and ignore that site. Instead use the [Mozilla Developer Network (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/) or the [official documentation](https://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a hash of destination address:

```js
let data = [
  {
    macProtocol: 'ip',
    ipProtocol: 'tcp',
    dstAddress: 'X.60.219.13',
    tx: 50,
    rx: 100,
  },
  {
    macProtocol: 'ip',
    ipProtocol: 'tcp',
    dstAddress: 'X.60.219.13',
    tx: 50,
    rx: 100,
  },
  {
    macProtocol: 'ip',
    ipProtocol: 'tcp',
    dstAddress: 'X.60.219.13',
    tx: 50,
    rx: 100,
  },
  {
    macProtocol: 'ip',
    ipProtocol: 'tcp',
    dstAddress: 'X.60.219.13',
    tx: 50,
    rx: 100,
  },
  {
    macProtocol: 'ip',
    ipProtocol: 'udp',
    dstAddress: 'X.172.63.97',
    tx: 500,
    rx: 750,
  },
  {
    macProtocol: 'ip',
    ipProtocol: 'udp',
    dstAddress: 'X.189.157.90',
    tx: 1000,
    rx: 2776,
  },
  {
    macProtocol: 'ip',
    ipProtocol: 'udp',
    dstAddress: 'X.212.176.21',
    tx: 70,
    rx: 300,
  },
];
const reducedArr = Object.values(
  /*obj:  {
  'X.212.176.21': {
    macProtocol: 'ip',
    ipProtocol: 'udp',
    dstAddress: 'X.212.176.21',
    tx: 70,
    rx: 300,
  }, 
  'X...':{},
  .....
  }*/
  data.reduce((obj, {dstAddress:dAdd,...curr}) => {
    if (dAdd in obj) {
      ['tx', 'rx'].forEach(x => (obj[dAdd][x] += curr[x]));
    } else {
      obj[dAdd] = curr;
    }
    return obj;
  }, {})
);

console.log(reducedArr);
```

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly. Not sure how to mark it as accepted or answered, so assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: @Matthew You can accept it by clicking the check button on the left of my answer post

Answer (score 0):

You should initiate an empty array, and iterate throw your data. Take a look on it:

```js
const ips = [{"macProtocol":"ip","ipProtocol":"tcp","dstAddress":"X.60.219.13","tx":50,"rx":100}, {"macProtocol":"ip","ipProtocol":"tcp","dstAddress":"X.60.219.13","tx":50,"rx":100}, {"macProtocol":"ip","ipProtocol":"tcp","dstAddress":"X.60.219.13","tx":50,"rx":100}, {"macProtocol":"ip","ipProtocol":"tcp","dstAddress":"X.60.219.13","tx":50,"rx":100}, {"macProtocol":"ip","ipProtocol":"udp","dstAddress":"X.172.63.97","tx":500,"rx":750}, {"macProtocol":"ip","ipProtocol":"udp","dstAddress":"X.189.157.90","tx":1000,"rx":2776}, {"macProtocol":"ip","ipProtocol":"udp","dstAddress":"X.212.176.21","tx":70,"rx":300}];
const result = [];

ips.map(ip => {
  let currentIp = result.find(item => item.dstAddress === ip.dstAddress);
  
  if (currentIp) {
     currentIp.tx += ip.tx
     currentIp.rx += ip.rx
     result.push(currentIp)
  } else {
    result.push(ip)
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: That's not how [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) should be used.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript's [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method to do that.

```js
var data = [
  {"macProtocol": "ip", "ipProtocol": "tcp", "dstAddress": "X.60.219.13", "tx":50, "rx":100},
  {"macProtocol": "ip", "ipProtocol": "tcp", "dstAddress": "X.60.219.13", "tx":50, "rx":100},
  {"macProtocol": "ip", "ipProtocol": "tcp", "dstAddress": "X.60.219.13", "tx":50, "rx":100},
  {"macProtocol": "ip", "ipProtocol": "tcp", "dstAddress": "X.60.219.13", "tx":50, "rx":100},
  {"macProtocol": "ip", "ipProtocol": "udp", "dstAddress": "X.172.63.97", "tx":500, "rx":750},
  {"macProtocol": "ip", "ipProtocol": "udp", "dstAddress": "X.189.157.90", "tx":1000, "rx":2776},
  {"macProtocol": "ip", "ipProtocol": "udp", "dstAddress": "X.212.176.21", "tx":70, "rx":300},
]


let result = data.reduce((arr, currentValue) => {
   
   let index = arr.findIndex(item => item.dstAddress === currentValue.dstAddress);
   
   if (index === -1) {
      arr.push(currentValue);
   } else {
       arr[index].tx += currentValue.tx;
       arr[index].rx += currentValue.rx;
   }
  
   return arr;
  }, []);
      
 console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could:

- create a new array
- cycle every item of your array and check if it exists on the new array
- if it exists then "sum" `tx` and `rx` values, else push it on the new array

```js
let array = [
  {"macProtocol": "ip", "ipProtocol": "tcp", "dstAddress": "X.60.219.13", "tx":50, "rx":100},
  {"macProtocol": "ip", "ipProtocol": "tcp", "dstAddress": "X.60.219.13", "tx":50, "rx":100},
  {"macProtocol": "ip", "ipProtocol": "tcp", "dstAddress": "X.60.219.13", "tx":50, "rx":100},
  {"macProtocol": "ip", "ipProtocol": "tcp", "dstAddress": "X.60.219.13", "tx":50, "rx":100},
  {"macProtocol": "ip", "ipProtocol": "udp", "dstAddress": "X.172.63.97", "tx":500, "rx":750},
  {"macProtocol": "ip", "ipProtocol": "udp", "dstAddress": "X.189.157.90", "tx":1000, "rx":2776},
  {"macProtocol": "ip", "ipProtocol": "udp", "dstAddress": "X.212.176.21", "tx":70, "rx":300},
];
let newArray = [];
array.forEach(item => {
  let itemExists = false;
  newArray.forEach(newItem => {
    if (newItem.dstAddress == item.dstAddress) {
      itemExists = true;
      newItem.tx += item.tx;
      newItem.rx += item.rx;
    }
  });
  if (!itemExists) {
    newArray.push(item);
  }
});
console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: Thanks! However, when I click "Run code Snippet" it has removed all the duplicates, but it has not combined the values of the x.60.219.13 rows?

Comment: @Matthew: I'm sorry, I didn't notice that I had to "sum" the values of `rx` and `tx`. Now I updated my answer.